# Java constructor explanation please?

Tags: java

I dont understand how a constructor works
In the following code i know that we have a class, then two variables. When you create a variable you create a container for a value, so by declaring the variables x and y we created two containers, and they contain 0,0.

why the constructor, why the a and b?

```
public class Point {
    public int x = 0;
    public int y = 0;

    //constructor
    public Point(int a, int b) {
        x = a;
        y = b;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you may need to find a good book on Java fundamentals...

Comment: In this particular case, x=0 and y=0 is redundant. Unless you also have a constructor `public Point(){}` which takes no arguments then the 0 values will always be overwritten. It is also even more redundant because instance integer variables start out initialized to 0 anyway in java.

Answer (score 3):

Constructors are used to initialize instances of classes.

Each instance's x and y values are initialized to what you pass in to the constructor, here, the parameters are named "a" and "b".

In general, direct public access to instance variables is frowned upon, instead they'd be accessed through getters and setters.

Comment: i am confused with how x and y = 0 and then they equal a and b

Comment: @FairFire Why? They start off as 0, before control reaches the constructor. The constructor then sets them to the values in a and b.

Comment: just delete the "= 0;" from the declaration of x and y if it is confusing you; the bit that really matters in your case is the values that get passed into the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

This constructor is used in another class. In this case it looks like you're trying to make a "point on a graph" so with that assumption in another class you would use this constructor to make an instance of the Point class.

```
public class Example {

  private Point pt;

  public static void main(String[]args) {

    pt = new Point(20,10);

  }

}
```

This example creates a new instance of the Point class where x is 20 and y is 10.

Answer (score 0):

We have the code here, I'll explain it line by line.

```
public class Point {
    public int x = 0;
    public int y = 0;

    //constructor
    public Point(int a, int b) {
        x = a;
        y = b;
    }
}
```

First of all we have the `public class Point {`, this is the start of the class. All of the classes functions/variables go inside of this brace.

```
public int x = 0;
public int y = 0;
```

x and y are being declared here. By declaring them *outside* of any of the funcions, we're making them global and accessible to the entire class. These two variables are `public` which means they can be accessed outside of the script, but because they are not `static`, they can only be called from outside of the script after a `new` instance of `Point` has been created.

`public Point(int a, int b) {`

This line of code is called the constructor. We can see this because it (a) doesn't have a return type and (b) shares the same name as the class. The instructor is called when a new instance of the class is created via the `new` keyword. I.E. `new Point()`.
`int a` and `int b` are two required variables, so you must create your new instance of this class like so `new Point(5, 10);` where 5 represents A and 10 represents B.

Inside of your constructor you are setting the variables x and y to contain the two values passed to the constructor. So X will become 5 using my example, and Y will become 10.

X and Y will not be 0 because they have both already been created using the value of 0, and are now being set to a different value.

It is important to note that a constructor does not have to have parameters, and it could simply be written as `public Point() {` if you do not need to pass any parameters to it.

Answer (score 0):

"Why the constructor? "
Answer: User "should" instantiate the class Point by giving 2 values to the variables. Which signifies whoever want to use Point, give value and use it. 
"Why a and b?"
Answer: 2 explicitly given user values for the variables of Point class. You can even do like this forgetting a and b:

```
enter code here: public class Point {
public int x = 0;
public int y = 0;

//constructor
public Point(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

}

Comment: This is your third answer; please stop now. While your enthusiasm it's appreciated, it's almost never appropriate to keep adding new answers, rather a single answer should be edited and improved. Take care to make your answer as easy to read and understand as possible-for example, this time you left in the "enter code here" text.

Comment: i am just new to this forum. thanks for telling about the editing thing. i will keep that i mind when needed. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain you by using a very easy understanding example so that you can be able to learn and adapt it with easily.

```
class store
{
    protected String nameproduct;
    protected String idproduct;

    public store(String nameproduct, String idproduct) {
        this.nameproduct = nameproduct;
        this.idproduct = idproduct;
    } 
}
```

Based on what code above that we have declared nameproduct and idproduct as a String. Why I use protected because when you inheritance this class to other class that STILL RELATED so you don't need to declare those variables. So the variables are like a raw material that ready to build and the constructor is tool to developed it.

Answer (score -1):

"x" and "y" values are initialized to what is passed from the constructor, in this case "a" and "b"

Answer (score -1):

When the Point class is instantiated x and y has value 0. But when the class is instantiated by giving user values it make use of this constructor and make the value of x and y as user intended.

Comment: this is not the case x = 0 and y=0 will occur at instantiation time unless they are in static blocks (which they are not)

Answer (score -1):

ie; one can create:

```
Point pt=new Point();  //point which has x and y as 0
```

OR

```
Point pt=new Point(10,5);  //point which has x=10 and y=5
```

Comment: The class has no default constructor.

Comment: For this example to be correct the class would need both `public Point() {` and `public Point(int a, int b) {` as constructors inside of the class. Where `public Point() {` is the default.